# Removing characters from each line in shellscript

Tags: shell, unix

I have a text file like below

```
   IMPALA COUNT :941 MONGO COUNT : 980
    IMPALA COUNT :78 MONGO COUNT : 78
    IMPALA COUNT :252 MONGO COUNT : 258
    IMPALA COUNT :3008 MONGO COUNT : 3064
```

I want to remove everything and keep like below

```
941 980
78 78
252 258
3008 3064
```

Can anybody suggest any shellscript for this.

Comment: Does your file have *exactly* the same form as your example? Exactly two entries per line, exactly two words before each colon, no space after the first colon, one space after the second colon, no digits before the colon, only digits after the colon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way:

```
cut -d':' -f2,3 file.txt | cut -d' ' -f1,5
```

Another:

```
awk '{print substr($3, 2) " " $7}' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

A sed solution extracting the two digits:

```
sed -r 's/[^0-9]*([0-9]+)[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*/\1 \2/g' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a few options:

```
grep -Eo '[0-9]+' file | paste -d " " - -
awk -F'[ :]+' '{print $4, $7}' file
awk -F: '{print $2+0, $3}' file
perl -lne '@matches = /(?<=:) *(\S+)/g; print join " ", @matches' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e 's/[^:]*: *\([0-9]*\) */\1 /g;s/ $//'
```

that is: Replace any sequence of non-colons `[^:]*`, followed by a colon and possibly spaces `: *`, followed by a sequence of digits and possibly spaces `\([0-9]*\) *`, by the digit sequence `\1` plus one space; afterwards delete the final space in the line.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -r 's/[^0-9]+://g' file
```

It just matches all the characters distinct of a number `[^0-9]+` followed by a `:` and remove them.

---

### Example

```
$ cat file
   IMPALA COUNT :941 MONGO COUNT : 980
    IMPALA COUNT :78 MONGO COUNT : 78
    IMPALA COUNT :252 MONGO COUNT : 258
    IMPALA COUNT :3008 MONGO COUNT : 3064

$ sed -r 's/[^0-9]+://g' file
941 980
78 78
252 258
3008 3064
```